# Usar Inner join com <ul> e <li>

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou tentando listar as Sub-Categorias dentro das suas respectivas Categorias com Inner Join, mas não estou conseguindo, veja o que esta acontecendo com o menu Categorias.

Abaixo relaciono o código usado...

```
        <?php

    include "../conexao.php";
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria INNER JOIN sub_categoria ON categoria.nome_cat = sub_categoria.nome_cat")or die(mysql_error());
    while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> <?php echo $nome_cat = $res['nome_cat'];?> </a>
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="prod_index_categoria.php?codcategoria=<?php echo $res['nome'];?>"><?php echo $res['nome'];?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <?php
    }
            ?>
            </ul>
```

Abaixo relaciono imagens das estruturas das tabelas...

Categoria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sub-Categoria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se os amigos puderem me ajudar a solucionar o problema, fazendo que as Categorias não se duplique, e as Sub-Categorias fique dentro de sua respectivas Categorias, ficarei muito agradecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que a solução que está tentando buscar acaba complicando mais ainda o seu projeto. De qualquer forma vai duplicar linhas desnecessárias e trazer dados irrelevantes pra sua consulta.

Tente do modo mais prático e talvez mais ágil pra sua aplicação que é um `WHILE` encadeado, mais ou menos assim:

```
<ul>
<?php

    include "../conexao.php";
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT codigo, nome_cat FROM categoria ORDER BY nome_cat") or die(mysql_error());

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$res['nome_cat'].'</a>';

        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT codigo, nome, nome_cat FROM sub_categoria WHERE nome_cat = '".$res['nome_cat']."' ORDER BY nome") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
                echo '<li><a href="prod_index_categoria.php?codcategoria='.$res2['codigo'].'">'.$res2['nome'].'</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo '</li>';

    }
?>
</ul>
```

Considerações:

- Procure sempre listar os campos que deseja em uma consulta sql (como utilizei), assim economiza processamento do banco de dados pra descobrir quais são todos (`*`) pra te trazer.
- Utilize índices nas suas tabelas e não nomes para referenciar outra tabela do banco de dados, além de espaço, são muito mais rápidos, veja [esse artigo](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql).

Espero que ajude, abraços

Comment: Funcionou perfeito Mastria... Muito obrigado pela solução e pela dica, pois vou dar uma olhada com muita atenção no artigo indicado por você. OBRIGADÃO!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Ao meu ver a sua query está ok, o problema é no relacionamento das tabelas, uma vez que você utilizao nome da categoria para tal relação. Pesquise e aplique os conceitos de `Foreign key` nas suas tabelas, que irá melhorar tanto a manutenção do banco quanto a performance.

----- Edit

Acabei de perceber, o que você está pedindo na query não é o que você quer receber, a consulta correta seria

```
SELECT s.codigo, s.nome as sub_categoria, c.nome as categoria FROM sub_categoria s INNER JOIN categoria c ON s.cod_cat = c.cod_cat;
```

Comment: Alterei na Tabela Sub-Categoria a coluna nome_cat para  cod_cat, e na Tabela Categoria a coluna codigo alterei para cod_cat, e apliquei as alterações no código PHP (SELECT) e deu o mesmo resultado. Alguma outra sugestão, pois esgotei a minha tentativa de solucionar esse problema, e também não encontro na Rede nenhuma Post sobre o assunto.